# Drupal 9: How to customise URL for multilingual site?

Tags: drupal, multilingual, drupal-modules, drupal-9, drupal-path-aliases

Im stuck with this...

I creating a multilingual site with Drupal 9 and i need to change the default base-url from http://example.com/en(language is English) or http://example.com/it (language is italian) based on node field "country". So i need to have to http://example.com/en-uk (if country is uk) or http://example.com/it-uk (if country is uk and language italian).

Is there a way to do this in Drupal 9?

I tried to set the pattern for url alias but is adding the language/language-country and is not working.